# Accessing JSON string parsed by Node's Express bodyParser()

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js, express

**Question:** What object is the JSON parsed to?

I'm successfully sending a JSON string to the server, but I haven't been able to access the object.

Client script, sending the JSON:

```
var loginCredentials= {
    "username":creds.username,
    "password":creds.password };

request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(loginCredentials),
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Login listener, waiting for and supposedly parsing the JSON:

```
function listen(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

    app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

        var util = require('util');
        console.log(util.inspect(req.body, false, null));
        console.log(req.body.username);

    });

    app.listen(8080, function() {
        console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    });
}
```

Which logs:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
{ '{"username":"username1","password":"badpassword"}': '' }
undefined
```

So it looks like my JSON is parsed right, but I'm trying to access it via req.body.username and it isn't stored there.

Comment: Try using simply `data: loginCredentials,` instead of `data: JSON.stringify(loginCredentials),`

Comment: @mccannf trying that now... Ah, good sir, post that as the answer, if you will. I was converting JSON to more JSON.. Too much JSON for one function, I guess ;) I wonder if I parsed it twice, would it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bodyParser doesn't know that you're sending JSON. It assumes the body to be standard `www-form-urlencoded`, and therefore parses all of it as a single key.

Instead, send the proper content-type with your request:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(loginCredentials),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType: "json" // response type
});
```

However, as mentioned in [Do Not Use bodyParser with Express.js](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html), you might just use the `express.json()` middleware only.

Comment: As of Express 4 many middlewares are not bundled by default and should be installed separately. See [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware)